# Is PHP capable of caching count call inside loop?

Tags: php

I know the more efficient way to have a loop over array is a foreach, or to store count in a variable to avoid to call it multiple times.
But I am curious if PHP have some kind of "caching" stuff like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($myarray); $i++) { /* ... */ }
```

Does it have something similar and I am missing it, or it does not have anything and you should code:

```
$count=count($myarray);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PHP does exactly what you tell it to. The length of the array may change inside the loop, so it may be *on purpose* that you're calling `count` on each iteration. PHP doesn't try to infer what you mean here, and neither should it. Therefore the standard way to do this is:

```
for ($i = 0, $length = count($myarray); $i < $length; $i++)
```

Comment: This works well, although I prefer to initialize $length outside of the loop control structure, in case I need to refer it to somewhere else within the code.

Comment: @Mike Depends on the purpose. If `$length` is only used inside the loop, putting it inside the loop initialization is more idiomatic. If you explicitly need it elsewhere, you should initialize it outside the loop.

Answer (score 6):

PHP will execute the count each time the loop iterates. However, PHP does keep internal track of the array's size, so count is a relatively cheap operation. It's not as if PHP is literally counting each element in the array. But it's still not free.

Using a very simple 10 million item array doing a simple variable increment, I get 2.5 seconds for the in-loop count version, and 0.9 seconds for the count-before-loop. A fairly large difference, but not 'massive'.

edit: the code:

```
$x = range(1, 10000000);
$z = 0;
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($x); $i++) {
    $z++;
}
$end = microtime(true);   // $end - $start = 2.5047581195831
```

Switching to do

```
$count = count($x);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

and otherwise everything else the same, the time is 0.96466398239136

Comment: Especially considering an array of that size.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is an imperative language, and that means it is *not supposed* to optimize away anything that can possibly have any effect. Given that it's also an interpreted language, it couldn't be done safely even if someone really wanted.

Plus, if you simply want to iterate over the array, you really want to use **foreach**. In that case, not only the count, but the *whole array* will be copied (and you can modify the original one as you wish). Or you can modify it in place using `foreach ($arr as &$el) { $el = ... }; unset($el);`. What I mean to say is that PHP (as any other language) often provides better solutions to your original problem (if you have any).

Comment: I don't agree with that *whole array would be copyed* as PHP is a Copy On Write language.